# how to set android resources with robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, resources, robolectric

I have an andorid test which should check a case of a boolean resource  `isFlag = true`.

```
isFlag = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isFlag);
```

Using robolectric, can I mock these resources?

Say I want to alter my `bool.xml` file according to the specific test.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Roboelectric simply reads the values of your resources... http://robolectric.org/using-qualifiers/

Comment: Using robolectric, can I mock these resources?

Comment: Why you would mock a resource which is static?

Comment: @MatPag why do you think it's static?

Comment: A resource doesn't change at runtime. By the way you without knowing what you have to do, you could create a custom testing flavor with the overwritten resource and make roboelectric load that resource instead of the default one

Comment: @MatPag can you please add it as answer + code example?

Comment: A resource may indeed change at runtime, using the RRO (Runtime Resource Overlay) framework in Android. Probably not used as much by app developers but OEMs use it to toggle feature flags, settings, strings and more.